# Converting JS file to run after XHR event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap toggle library](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in a Django web application. This includes a [JS file](https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.js) that runs when the page load is completed.

My page includes a modal form generated over AJAX. Once the form is loaded, I need to re-execute the JS file to convert checkboxes to toggles in the generated form.

I've modified the signature of the [JS file](https://gicdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.js) from:

```
+function ($) {
    ....
}(jQuery);
```

to:

```
toggler = function ($) {
    ....
}
```

and am calling `toggler($);` after the XHR response is successfully handled.

Is this the "correct" way to trigger rich controls if I have forms generated over AJAX? If not, what should I be doing?

Comment: Do you use jquery ajax method to populate the form?

Comment: Nope, for now it's all raw `XMLHttpRequest` but it's early days and I'm open to changing to jquery `.ajax()` if it makes my life easier in the long run @Lorenzo

Comment: have you tried to init the toggle manually with `$('#toggle').bootstrapToggle()` after the form is generated?

Comment: No visible changes triggered by doing that even on the console. I'm sure the selector is correct.